# What does View type mean?

Tags: android, android-view, android-adapter

getItemViewType method of [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) class should

> Get the type of View that will be created by getView(int, View, ViewGroup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all items in an Adapter need to have the same View to represent them.  The view type is just an int that says which type it is-  basically an enum defined at run time.  If there's only 1 view, they should all return 0.  If there's multiple views, then each type should return a unique id between 0 and numTypes-1.

Comment: view here refer to parent view